# Register Google API Access in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, google-play-console, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to register access to Google Developer account via API in Visual Studio 2022
It's asking for a client ID which Google console gave me, but I can't seem to find the Client Secret anywhere

[image: Visual Studio dialog]

[image: Google Play Console OAuth 2.0 Client credential I created]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution.

When you create new OAuth 2.0 credentials on Google Cloud > Apis & Services, select Desktop app for the Application type

Comment: Thanks or saving my sanity. Spent hours frustratingly following out-of-date docs and creating credentials (of other types) that either didn't have secrets, or resulted in opaque 'Invalid request' errors down the track. This worked, but is not mentioned ANYWHERE in docs I've found, even 1.5 years later.